# How to read from text files in classpath across directories?

Tags: java

I'm working on a program (with JavaSE 1.6) that will read from text files located in the project's classpath.

The files are in a different folder than the class that's trying to access them, though, and directing my code to their location is baffling me.

The class I'm running is located in a package in the "src/test/java" folder, while the text files are separated into multiple folders (for organizational purposes) within the "src/main/resources" folder.

I'm currently trying to point to the text files using the following code, but after the line runs, 'in' receives a null value:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/src/main/resources/<folder name here>/<file name here>.txt");
```

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to specify the file like this if it's in a different directory, so I'm a bit lost on how to proceed...I've searched Google and StackOverflow and found plenty of resources for reading files from the classpath but nothing about how to point the InputStream to a file outside of the class' package. Can anyone please tell me whether or not it's possible and, if so, how it can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual answer depends entirely on how you're building/packaging this.

It *looks* like a Maven project, in which case the `src/xxx/yyy` folders aren't in your actual class hierarchy. After building, `src/main/resources` will be at the *root* of your classpath, meaning the classpath resource is simply `your/folders/and/file.txt`.

If it's *not* a Maven project, then it depends on how you *are* building it.

Comment: Oh wow, I completely forgot to mention that...You're right, this code IS part of a Maven project. I just tried your advice, and the code is functioning as predicted now. Thanks very much!! I really need to work on remembering to include crucial details like that in my questions...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `/src` from your path. Assuming `src` is on your build path (in your IDE), then the compiled code will contain only the folders inside it directly at the root. For example,

```
/src
    /main/resources
        file.txt
```

will produce

```
/main/resources/file.txt
```

Now if `/src/main/resources` in on the buildpath, you need to remove the whole thing and the file will appear on the root. Its `InputStream` would be accessible as

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/<folder name here>/<file name here>.txt");
```

Example

```
/src/main/resources  // buildpath
    /spring
        applicationContext.xml
/src/main/java  // buildpath
    /mypackage
        MyClass.java
```

would be accessible like

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/spring/applicationContext.xml");
```

which means the jar (if that's how you compiled and packaged it) would be structured as

```
/spring
    applicationContext.xml
/mypackage
    MyClass.class
```

The method `getResourceAsStream(String)` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) says:

> - If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of    the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
> - Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>     modified_package_name/name
>
> Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').

Answer (score 1):

For the same jar, this:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass()
    .getResourceAsStream("/<folder name here>/<file name here>.txt");
```

This can use a relative path with respect to the class's package, but here it is absolute.

This does the following (considering a Maven build):

- The source file, under `src/main/resources/<folder-path>/<file>` is typically copied to `target/classes/<folder-path>/<file>`. Often the IDE uses this path for internal runs.
- On a build a jar file is produced under `/target/<project>.jar`.
- Opening that jar with 7zip/WinZip would show `<folder-path>/<file>`.

Running the jar it is important that the paths are case-sensitive.

***If the resource is in another directory***

Then use the SystemClassLoader (having all class paths).

```
InputStream in = ClassLoader
    .getSystemResourceAsStream("<folder name here>/<file name here>.txt");
```

This uses absolute paths I think. Such a usage might benefit from the jars having a (single?) META-INF/INDEX.LIST (covering several jars).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, src is not in your classpath.  Change the path to the corresponding file under your classes directory.